# VS 2012 with C++ group include/lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, project-management, libraries

I am currently working on a large project with a friend and it's time we started working on the same files. We have a dropbox, and we're wondering if there was some way to configure the project so all necessary extra includes/.libs for the libraries we are using in there, so if we change libraries or whatever the other won't have to go download and install anything.

For example, he's working in ***OpenGL*** and I'm working with ***Lua*** and other libraries. Is there some way to combine all these into ***dropbox folders*** and have the project link/compile out of those?

Comment: Visual studio team foundation service is free for small teams, I believe. http://tfs.visualstudio.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, VS2010 has a wide array of super useful macros built in for project sharing.

- Create an `external` folder in your project to hold all libraries you'll be using
- All of your include/lib directories should use a SolutionDir macro, as an example one of my additional include directories is

> $(SolutionDir)\external\glew-1.9.0\include

The **SolutionDir** macro is simply the location of the solution relative to the computer. This means two computers could have completely different paths to the solution, but the macro correctly tells the compiler where to find `\external\libraryFile\include`

Here's an image in an attempt to make it more clear:
[A larger version someone can actually read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbgPc.png)
[image]

edit: VS has many other useful macros out there, if you do not want it specifically in the solution look into other directory options VS provides.