# How to specify the directory of a .config file in C++ code?

Tags: c++

I have a C++ program that I built using Visual Stuidos.  It has to read some variables from a .config file.  I notice that when I run the program from VS (i.e. I open the VS solution and press the "Start Without Debugging" button), it can't find the .config file unless it's in the "release" or "debug" directory.  However, I'd like to be able to run the program from the VS solution, while keeping the .config file in the same directory as the .sln file.  Is there a way I can set the path of the .config file to this directory, perhaps somewhere in the source code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would take advantage of Visual Studios directory macros and set an additional include path in your solution directory, I answered a [question previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180454/vs-2012-with-c-group-include-lib/16180518#16180518) on this site relating to include directories, so here is a diagram I created:

bigger link [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbgPc.png)
[image]

Don't pay attention to the text on the left side, but the black text on the right side is what you're looking for. `$(SolutionDir)` is a macro that finds the directory of your solution, and adding this will allow your program to have access to this directory during the program.

Comment: I don't see how changing the include path helps his program open a file at runtime.

Comment: @Need4Sleep:  Good point.  I tried adding $(SolutionDir) to my "Additional Include Directories".  Got the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can call GetModuleFileName to get the full path to your exe file. From there you can remove the lowest level (/debug or /release) to get the project path.

That should get you what you asked for, but what you asked for is not a good approach. Putting your config file in your exe directory will encounter problems later on with non-admin user rights. The recommended place for such files can be found by calling SHGetFolderPath, where you can create an accessible folder for your app.

Comment: Thanks, ScottMcP-MVP.  Could you show me an example of the syntax for calling SHGetFolderPath?  Can't seem to find a good example on Google (at least, not an example that I can make sense of!!).

Answer (score 0):

- However, I'd like to be able to run the program from the VS solution,
  while keeping the .config file in the same directory as the .sln
  file.

Just set `Project Properties|Debugging|Working Directory` to $(SolutionDir). Or any directory you want.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, kotlomoy.  I don't have access to my program right now.  But when I do (Tuesday, May 28th), I'll let you know if it worked for me.